# How to use "multiple arrays" in "each" cycle in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

i want the product pages marked as PageType = 'item' (inside only one category) to display different HTML code according to language mutation of a webpage. What i've achieved so far is that on every mutation page is the same content X times (x = object items such as "eng": "categoryname" )

```js
var html = `
  <div class="">
   <a class="" href="#" target="_blank">
    <img src="different images with site language mutation" alt="banner">
   </a>
  </div>
`;



var langcode = $('html').attr('lang');

var maincat = [];

$(".breadcrumbclass").each(function() {
  var vat = $(this).text();
  maincat.push(vat);
});


var mycategory = maincat[1];


$.each(langmutations, function(key, val) {
  if (((PageType == 'item') || (PageType === 'category')) && (mycategory === langmutations[langcode])) {
    $('.classForPastingMyHtml').after(html);

  }
});



//This is what i have in JS
var langmutations0 = {
  eng: 'categoryname',
  de: 'kategoriename',
  ru: 'categorija'
};
//or
var langmutations1 = [
  ["eng", "categoryname"],
  ["de", "kategoriename"],
  ["ru", "categorija"]
];

//I believe this is PHP style
var langmutations2 = ['eng' => 'categoryname', 'de' => 'kategoriename', 'ru' => 'categorija'];

//This could be multiple array in PHP style ? I want to have this in JS
var multiple = [eng => [“cat” => “categoryname”, “banner” => “link”], de => [“cat” => “kategoriename”, “banner” => “link”], ru => [“cat” => “categorija”, “banner” => “link”]];
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I think that i should use something like multiple array, but don't know if that exists in JS or how to structure it. Or maybe javascript object that would respond to that PHP style.

Comment: A php *associative array* is in JS an *object*. `['eng' => 'categoryname', 'de' => 'categoryname', 'ru' => 'categorija']` in php is `{eng: 'categoryname', de: 'categoryname',ru:'categorija'}` in js

Comment: Please add the value/initialization of `mutacie`. In German, the translation is Kategorie/Kategoriename, btw.

Comment: I can't make sense of your code. You have a `$.each` and call a function with key and value parameters, but inside the function you never use key or value. Also, why would you have PHP-style associative arrays in javascript? And why have `langmutations1` when `langmutations0` does the job?

Comment: Well i am noob, self-taught and i dont know how to use those key values in function in order to insert different html for different langueges. That PHP was just  demonstration.- wanted to show you what i want in Javascript bu am not able to create it.

Comment: What is in `mycategory`? Where is `langmutations` initialized?

Comment: mycategory is variable that is used to store the text of actual category you are actually on. Langmutations is not initalized its just in the each. cos i don't know how to use it so that it will work like i described it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some simple code to get you started:

```js
var multiple = {
     eng : {"cat" : "categoryname", "banner" : "link"}, 
     de : {"cat" : "Kategoriename", "banner" : "link"}, 
     ru : {"cat" : "categorija", "banner" : "link"}
};

var language = 'de';
var translations = multiple[language];

var cat = translations.cat;

console.log(cat);

//Show all translations
$.each(multiple, function(language,translations){
    var cat = translations.cat;
    console.log(cat);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It uses objects inside objects with language as keys.

Comment: Aaaa so this is thy way i store my key value pairs so that i can use them. Well in the meantime i figured it out :D  What i still haven't though is how to run them through each cycle so that it throws these different pairs for different languages sites. I mean i don't know how to use those function(key, val) in function body...

Comment: Then i do not understand why is there  var language = 'de';  - why would you create var for one language,

Comment: It is two examples, one for how to use it to translate in a language, and another example for how to use $.each. The variable names `language,translations` in the second example refer to different variables than those in the first example and shadow the ones of the first example. This is called scoping.

Comment: Well i understand a little bit and know that stackoverflow is not page to instantly give me the code i want...but since i have low experiences with JS i would appreciate if you gave me hand with what should be in  each cycle so that i can have at least AHA moment, since i was not able to figure it out.

Comment: The problem is from your code I can't see what you want to do. The first example shows how to use an object with translation to get one translation for "cat". The second example shows how to get a list of "cat"egories in the 3 languages. The latter should be useful when you append html using `after`. All that is left to do for you is to produce the html using "cat" and "banner" on the translations variable.